# How to know which button is pressed next c#

Tags: c#, button, boolean

I am developing an order taking system for a pizza shop and I would like to press the size of the pizza, and then add whatever size button was pressed + what pizza to a Listbox. for example small size + Hawaiian. this is how I have tried to do it so far however it only works once because I am not sure how to reset bool.

```
    bool ButtonSmallClicked = false;

    private void ButtonSmall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonSmallClicked = true;
    }

    private void ButtonHawaiian_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ButtonSmallClicked == true)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", buttonSmall.Text, buttonHawaiian.Text));
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean "reset bool" ? set it back to false ? "ButtonSmallClicked = false;"

Comment: @VietDD yes exactly. im not sure how

Comment: Consider to use radio buttons for pizza sizes (you can make them to look like actual buttons), than combine selected button value with selected pizza type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.Tag` property and save clicked value to the variable for further processing.

```
public class SelectedPizza
{
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Format() => $"{Size} {Name}";
}

public class MyForm
{
    private readonly SelectedPizza _selectedPizza;

    public MyForm()
    {
        buttonSmallSize.Tag = "Small";
        buttonSmallSize.Click += ButtonSizeClick;
        buttonLargeSize.Tag = "Large";
        buttonLargeSize.Click += ButtonSizeClick;
       
        buttonHawaiian.Tag = "Hawaiian";
        buttonHawaiian.Click += ButtonNameClick;

        _selectedPizza = new SelectedPizza();
    }   

    private void ButtonSizeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        _selectedPizza.Size = button.Tag.ToString();
    }

    private void ButtonNameClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        _selectedPizza.Name = button.Tag.ToString();
        
        listBox1.Items.Add(_selectedPizza.Format());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is it useful for you?

```
private void ButtonSmall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ButtonSmallClicked ==true)
              ButtonSmallClicked = false;
        else
              ButtonSmallClicked = true;
    }
```

or

```
 private void ButtonHawaiian_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ButtonSmallClicked == true)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", buttonSmall.Text, buttonHawaiian.Text));
ButtonSmallClicked == false;
        }
}
```

Comment: _"what do you mean??"_ seems more useful as a comment on the question to request more clarity.

Comment: Why not do `ButtonSmallClicked = !ButtonSmallClicked;`?